# Intelli J IDE do not recognize JavaFX SDK

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I try to use Intelli J IDE 2020.1 for JavaFX project.

According to [IDE creator suggestion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) I have to download JavaFX SDK [form this site](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).

After downloading and unzipping JavaFX directory, SDK should be added to SDK list via **Project Structure->Platform Settings->SDKs->Add JDK.**
Both JavaFX 11 and JavaFX 15 directories, as well and their "lib" subdirectories brings error dialog

*"The Selected direcotry is not valid home for JDK"*

Does anybody downloaded JavaFX SDK and added it to Intelli J project in the similar ways?

Does anybody knows what is a criteria for Intelli J to recognize directory as valid JDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well JavaFX should be added **as library** and **not as SDK**.

More detailed description [may be found here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij)